# Excel Macro to break out tabs to account specific workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CostCenterMarco2014()

Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation
Dim CC As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim ccf As Range
Dim ccl As Range
Dim tt As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

'   Turn off events and screen updating
    With Application
        xlCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set thisbook = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Iteration over SAP cost centers
    For i = 2 To 30
        CC = thisbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
        thisbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value = CC
        thisbook.Worksheets("Summary").Calculate
        Workbooks.Add
        thisbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:Z100").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:Z").AutoFit

        ' Iteration over 5 sheets
        For j = 4 To 7
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Name = thisbook.Worksheets(j).Name

            'Copy header row
            thisbook.Worksheets(j).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Range("A1")

            ' Depending on the format of header row
            'tt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
            tt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
            With thisbook.Worksheets(j)
                Set ccf = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=CC, after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

                If Not ccf Is Nothing Then
                    Set ccl = .Range("A:A").FindPrevious(after:=ccf)
                    .Range(.Cells(ccf.Row, 1), .Cells(ccl.Row, tt)).Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Range("A2")
                End If
            End With

            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
            thisbook.Worksheets(j).Range("A1").Select
        Next j

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Summary"
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Select



        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\REDACTED\2.February 2019\Monthly Expense Report February 2019-" & CC '& ".xlsx"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next i


'   Turn on events and screen updating
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

So I won't profess to knowing a whole lot about coding in general. I took a couple classes in college so I feel like I can at least feel my way through this one. This macro was given to me by someone who is no longer at my company. Most of it is working as intended and it worked completely last month.

This month however the Iteration over 5 sheets section just doesn't seem to be working. I tried to step through the macro and it creates a new workbook and pastes the summary info inside, but then when it gets to copying the tabs it doesn't copy any of the 4 details tabs I need or their name even.

What I end up with is all of the individual cost centers in their own file with summary as intended, but the detail tabs are not being copied. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the nasty statement `On Error Resume Next` so that when it fails you will see a helpful error message. We should not routinely just ignore errors.

Comment: You could also leave the screen updating and display alerts working while debugging. (You are fumbling in the dark otherwise.)

Comment: That definitely does help. I was so fixated on the sheets thing that I didn't even think about it. It's something on line 39.    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Comment: Which is line 39 and what is the error message?

Comment: Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

the `after` parameter is expecting a single sheet reference, not a reference to the entire `Worksheets` collection.

If, for example, you want to add a sheet to the end then you can use `Count` to locate the last sheet, using it as the sheet index:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add _ 
    after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
```

---

Remove `On Error Resume Next` unless, and until, the code is fully tested and working. Even then, this should be a last resort and used to circumvent a specific issue that can safely be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for that. I made that change, but now i'm getting an error at "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Name = thisbook.Worksheets(j).Name" (Subscript out of Range)

Comment: j is referring to a sheet index that does not exist. If there are 4 sheets and j is 5, it fails.

Comment: In my main file I have 10 or so tabs. It was my thought that this section should grab sheet j where j=4,5,6,7 from my main file as it loops and put it into my summary file before closing/saving it. Is there another way to look at/accomplish this?

Comment: Is there something I could include before the iteration step that creates enough new sheets in the individual workbooks for the iteration to work? Or am I thinking about this wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I am only responding to and answering the initial question. You need to work on solving new issues that have arrived (since removing On Error Resume Next). You can always create a new question if you remain stuck.

Comment: I actually just got it working. Removing "thisbook.Worksheets(j).Range("A1").Select" Seems to have let everything work. As for the tabs thing I forgot that you can just increase the number of tabs in a new workbook by default in excel options. Will Update question with answer.

Comment: Glad you sorted. There is no need to update, or revise, the original question. An answer can just be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the nasty error blocks I had to add `(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)`as referenced above. After that I was getting an error at `thisbook.Worksheets(j).Range("A1").Select` which I solved by just deleting it since it didn't seem like it was needed. Everything seems to be working appropriately now. Thanks for all the help.